# ObjectBox Source entity has no ID (should have been put before)

Tags: java, android, objectbox

I got an exception while trying to insert new object.

Logcat:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Source entity has no ID (should have been put before)  
at io.objectbox.relation.ToMany.internalCheckApplyToDbRequired(ToMany.java:599)
```

Insert function:

```
public static void setSyncData(long contactId, SyncerData syncData) {
    final Box<SyncerData> box = getObjectBoxStore().boxFor(SyncerData.class);
    SyncerData syncerData = box.query().equal(SyncerData_.id, contactId).build().findFirst();
    if (syncerData == null) {
        syncerData = new SyncerData();
        syncerData.setPhoneOrIdKey(ContactData.generateId(Phone.EMPTY, contactId));
    }
    syncerData.setSyncerDetailsToMany(syncData.getSyncerDetailsToMany());
    box.put(syncerData);
}
```

What that's mean, that I can't put new object ToMany list before I added to object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's related to https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/104.

In essence setting a relation to a new plain List is somewhat problematic because ObjectBox lacks the change tracking, which is available in the `ToMany`class. We'll look how to sync that in a future release.

Please try something like the following:

```
toMany.clear();
toMany.addAll(newList);
```